# What is the source of the index in a ColumnDataSource created from a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, bokeh

Dataframes naturally come with an index, i.e. those set of row headers we can think of them as. When I construct a ColumnDataSource in bokeh to capture the information in that dataframe for plotting and annotating in a HoverTool I see that the hover tool has a built in `( "index" , "$index" )` tooltip available. Will this index be identical to my dataframe's index or is it simply the row index in the ColumnDataSource

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The special variable `$index` simply displays the row index of the column data source (it can't be a pandas index in general, because although CDS *may* be created from data frames, they do not *have to*). If you want to include the pandas dataframe index you can add it:

```
In [5]: d = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=[1,2,3], b=[2,3,4]))

In [6]: d.index
Out[6]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=3, step=1)

In [7]: source = ColumnDataSource(d)

In [8]: source.add(d.index, 'index')
```

This field can be accessed in a hover tool with the standard and general `@colname` syntax for any standard CDS column (so in this specific case: `@index`)

Comment: I was going to uncover this later today once that code got written up but launched a preemptive Q. Good to know I'll have to tuck the pandas index away. Nice `add` syntax too, I wasn't familiar with that capability.